# Open Word file stored in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

We successfully add word documents in our SQL Server (varbinary column) using some web forms, then, we want some of our staff to be able to download them.

We have some code to display it, but sometimes it does display (in my local environment), sometimes it does not, but then, when it goes live to Production. So, we just want to download it, it doesn't matter if it opens or if it does not (in case you don't have Word installed), we just want to have it downloaded, something like the "Save as..." function. Because in my local environment it works well, but when it goes live to a IIS server, we are not able to retrieve the file (I am guessing, it is because it opens WORD automatically).

Here is the code to retrieve it.

```
    public string showDoc(int id, int numRef)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".docx";
        Db.Open();
        string cuerito = "select doc from tbl_references where [userId]=@id and [refNum]=@numRef";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cuerito, base.Db);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numRef", numRef);
        using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    int size = 1024 * 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    int readBytes = 0;
                    int index = 0;

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                    {
                        while ((readBytes = (int)dr.GetBytes(0, index, buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
                        {
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                            index += readBytes;
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
        Db.Close();
        return fileName;
    }
```

Is there a way in C# just to do this? Not display but only download it from SQL Server?

EB.

Comment: IIUC, you are already reading the file,  why can't you write it somewhere else?  Wouldn't that be a "download"?

Comment: Not at all clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Thing is, when it goes to production (IIS Server), this solution does not work. It only works in my local environment, because it automatically opens Word (that is my guessing). You know, something like the "Save as..." function, to have it downloaded (whether I have Word installed or not).

Comment: Where is any reference to Word in provided code?

Comment: "does not work" means what? What error or unexpected behaviour occurs, exactly? All the code above does is read some data from a binary field and write it to a stream, which gets written to the disk on the server. There's no need to save the file to disk before you offer it for download, you can simply stream the data directly to the client - there are tons of examples and previous questions containing working examples of this process if you google it. They will work with any file, none of this is specific to Word files. And none of it relates to interop in any way - I'll remove that tag.

Comment: BTW whether the file downloads directly to the user's disk or is opened up (saved in a temp folder on the user's machine) is largely down to the config of the user's machine, which browser they use, whether the Word plugin is installed in that browser, their general download settings. You can set HTTP headers (again google it) which hint to the browser to just save the file instead of trying to open it, but ultimately it's in the control of the browser, not the server.

Comment: this code will be saving the file to the local area on the SERVER...what code do you then have to flush this file to the client's machine?...and also...based on the code I assume you plan for the loop to only return one record...otherwise you are creating data with the same name over and over again...I see no interop here going on at all...SQL server & IIS just know you have binary data and are saving it to a file named docx...there's no call to open the file here

Comment: I was wondering something with the interop could be done, perhaps I was missing something which could help. With "does not work", I meant, it literally does nothing when it goes to a production server, but if I understand correctly. then it is written in the server (which in my local environtment, means my PC), and that settles it. Can you point me in the right direction? I swear I have seen like 2393 examples, but none can't seem to really fulfill. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank all of you. I have a better understanding of this. This is kinda new to me.

Comment: We had a similar requirement. Way we handled was, having all these files in a shared network path. configure the \\sharedpath\ in a table. All word docs are saved in the path are mapped in the table config and pulled from there.  Second approach would be, when you retrieve the data (word doc) from database, save  the file in the local temp folder of the user's computer. So Internet \Temp Path\ will have this file. From there, you can copy it to C (or) where ever it requires to go

Comment: Here's one reasonably simple example. There are dozens more similar ones with slight variations on the theme.  But this is the general idea. https://ygtechme.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/downloading-file-from-database-using-c-asp-net/

Comment: Can you post it as an answer (the explanation), so I can choose it as the one I wanted? Thanks.

Comment: @HenryB I've posted an answer, I'm assuming it was the bit you were referring to, let me know if it needs amending.

Answer (score 0):

All the code above does is read some data from a binary field and write it to a stream, which gets written to the disk on the server. There's no need to save the file to disk before you offer it for download, you can simply stream the data directly to the client - there are tons of examples and previous questions containing working examples of this process if you google it. They will work with any file, none of this is specific to Word files. And none of it relates to interop in any way.

BTW whether the file downloads directly to the user's disk or is opened up (saved in a temp folder on the user's machine) is largely down to the config of the user's machine, which browser they use, whether the Word plugin is installed in that browser, their general download settings. You can set HTTP headers (again google it) which hint to the browser to just save the file instead of trying to open it, but ultimately it's in the control of the browser, not the server.

Here's one reasonably simple example of sending binary data from a database table as a file download: https://ygtechme.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/downloading-file-from-database-using-c-asp-net/. There are dozens more similar ones with slight variations on the theme available online. But this is the general idea.

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted already does what you ask for.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Read the comments above. The code saves a file to the server's disk, it doesn't send anything for download